# tinymce edtor does not load, once dojo is loaded

Tags: dojo, tinymce

I have downloaded the latest version of tinyMce and builded a sample html file with a text area and added the code for loading the tinyMce editor in text area and it worked fine.
I tried to load the tinyMce editor in a text area using the same code, in an application where dojo frame work is used( the dojo js will be initially loaded). The tinyMce editor is not getting loaded within this application. Can some one help me to dig this problem or any one of you had faced a similar issue? Any help will be much appreciated 
thx Jijo John
amt.in

Comment: as long as tinymce 4 is beta, you can save yourself some trouble and use the latest stable release of tinymce 3